Created a table with IDENTITY(0,1) on the id, after inserting values id set to 5. Create a column which checks if first letter uppercase
Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I want emp_id to be auto_incremented like 1,2,3,4...
I want first_name and last_name to only allow inputs with the first letter as uppercase.

I created a table with this SQL code:
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) 
        CHECK (first_name LIKE UPPER(LEFT(first_name, 1))) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(40) 
        CHECK(last_name LIKE UPPER(LEFT(last_name, 1))) NOT NULL,
    birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
    sex char(1) CHECK (sex IN ('M','F')) NOT NULL,
    salary MONEY NOT NULL,
    super_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    branch_id INT DEFAULT NULL
);

I inserted a first round of values with:
INSERT INTO employee(first_name, last_name, birth_date, sex, salary)
VALUES ('David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000);

After inserting values, emp_id got set to 5, I intended it to be 1.
first_name VARCHAR(20) CHECK(first_name LIKE UPPER(LEFT(first_name,1))) NOT NULL,
and
last_name VARCHAR(40) CHECK(last_name LIKE UPPER(LEFT(last_name,1))) NOT NULL,
are my attempts of assuring the first character of first_name and last_name are uppercase. Instead, these columns ONLY allow the input to be 1 uppercase letter, tested that by changing ('David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000); to ('D', 'W', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000);. Any help?

Is it possible some prior attempts to insert have failed? Or that the instance has been restarted or failed over? Anyway, if you want a sequence with no gaps, IDENTITY isn't your solution. Maybe sequence, but it all depends on what you want to happen later when someone deletes row where id = 1. Does everything get renumbered to eliminate the gap?

Yes, my goal is for rows to get renumbered if one of them gets deleted to remove the gap.

Not sure what you mean by "Is it possible some prior attempts to insert have failed? Or that the instance has been restarted or failed over?", elaborate if you will, I'm new to this as you might`ve guessed.

If you say INSERT and then the insert fails because your check constraint was violated, you used up an identity value. SQL Server issues them without checking to see if the insert ultimately succeeded.

Okay, that's exactly what happened. Must've failed 4 inputs before a successful one

These really should be two completely different questions.

It is likely that before your successful insert, there were multiple failures, rollbacks, or a service disruption. SQL Server does not track whether an insert succeeds; it uses up the identity value anyway. And it caches a certain number of values so that you can and will see gaps in the sequence over time whenever there is a service restart or failover (IIRC there's a trace flag to override this, so no identity values are cached, but just don't - it will hurt performance at scale).
What to do about this depends on the desired behavior.

If you just don't like gaps, get over it; they're going to happen. Identity just shouldn't be used for scenarios where the numbers need to be contiguous or to have tangible meaning. They're meant to be arbitrary, surrogate values.
If you need there to be no gaps, stop using identity. Look into sequence and/or rolling your own MAX+1 with HOLDLOCK solution.
If you only care that the numbers are in order when presenting the data and you don't really care what the value for any given row is from query to query, just apply ROW_NUMBER() at presentation time.
If you need the numbers to renumber themselves every time an existing row is deleted, you definitely don't want to use identity. Again, this seems like it should just generate the numbers at query time. What's the point of storing them if they're just an ordering that you have to constantly maintain?

Next:
CHECK(first_name LIKE UPPER(LEFT(first_name,1)))

This means that any string > one character will fail because you're saying "where the value entered is LIKE the first character of the value entered (LIKE is the same as = when there are no wildcards). Are you trying to ensure that the first letter is always capitalized? Why? What if my last name is da Costa? In some cultures lower case is important. If you really want to trounce all over that, then you need to check using a case- or binary-sensitive collation, e.g.:
CHECK (LEFT(first_name,1) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN
  = UPPER(LEFT(first_name, 1))

Note that this also allows Da costa which may also not be intended or appreciated.
